# How to get the portNumber used by a host in a peer to peer network

Tags: java, sockets, p2p, port-number

So I am working on a poker game that is using a peer-to-peer network architecture for a school project. Right now I am currently working on the whole multiplayer element of the game and I am designing my peers to be connecting a ring style format such as what is seen below
[image: peer to peer ring format]

So for my algorithm, when a user executes the program they give a port number and a ServerSocket is created. The ServerSocket will listen for new players to join, and then if and only if the member variable nextPeer is null then we will assign nextPeer to this socket and continue listening. If the variable nextPeer is not null, then the client will take the information of the socket trying to join and send that information to the nextPeer variable until a client with a null nextpeer variable is found and the peer tying to join will be connected to the client with a null nextPeer variable found. The code for the creating a new game is found below.

```
public void createNewGame(int credits) throws IOException
{
    this.player = new Player(1, credits);
    this.routingTable = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    (new Thread(this)).run();

    String s = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input a s or S to begin game");
    while(!s.equals("s") || !s.equals("S"))
    {
        s = in.nextLine();
    }

    this.listening = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.listening = true;
    while(listening)
    {
        Socket newPlayer;
        try {
            newPlayer = connection.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            newPlayer = null;
        }


        if (newPlayer != null) {
            if (this.nextPeer == null) {
                this.nextPeer = newPlayer;
                try {
                    this.messaging = new MessageCenter(newPlayer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error making MessageCenter");
                }
            } else {
                String[] message = { newPlayer.getInetAddress().getHostName(),
                        String.valueOf(newPlayer.getPort()) };
                Thread worker = new Thread(new MessagerThread("NP", message, this.messaging));
                worker.run();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am stuck because I cant quite find out how to let the last player to join know the port number used by the player to begin the name, or the host. Looking at the image of the ring architecture above, how does system 9 make the connection to system 1? Can I use the port number I supplied to the ServerSocket object for this?

Comment: How does your system know that the 9th client is the last one, how does the 8th client know not to connect back to the first one?

Comment: I have a couple basic methods for this. For one the user can enter a max number of players or connections or if the player types in s or S then the last client to try to connect will be established and any nex connections are rejected.

Comment: Well, in any case yes, you'd always use the same port number you've chosen for all communication.

Comment: Choose a circular-queue type of data structure for storing the socket info of clients!

Comment: After some research i realized i was not doing anything correctly lol i have decided to use a routing table that all peers share to fix this issue, but thank you to all who helped me out! it is much appriciated